# Using Core Text for input

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, macos, ipad

I'd like to make a rich text type editor using Core Text (ideally for iPad but I'm pretty sure I can't get iPad specific examples due to the NDA)

I have no idea really where to start. I'd like to keep the interaction models without having to rewrite them, so would I be layering stuff on top of a text view? Then how do I keep the overlays in the right spot during scrolling?

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone SDK, at least as of 3.1 (for which documentation is available to the public), does not have Core Text. It's possible that they've added Core Text in 3.2, but if that's the case, nobody here can answer you about that; ask on [the Developer Forums](https://devforums.apple.com/) instead. (I don't know because I'm not an iPhone developer, so I don't have access to that info. I can only read what's public.)

On Mac OS X, Core Text is only for *drawing* text. You would have to handle all input, plus selection and insertion-point drawing, yourself. That is, you would have to write your own NSText and NSTextView from the ground up. If you were programming the Mac, it would be easier to simply use the built-in NSTextView.